# Métodos de pagamento Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Estou atualmente pesquisando como integrar métodos de pagamentos em um aplicativo feito no Xamarin-Forms, mas até agora não obtive muito sucesso na minhas buscas,  a maioria dos serviços de integração de pagamentos mobile como PagSeguro, MercadoPago, Cielo possuem documentação apenas para apps nativos. Alguém sabe de algum serviço que possa ser integrado ao Xamarin ou algum meio de adaptar estes serviços? Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Eu fiz isso no meu aplicativo. Eu uso o PagSeguro e não achei uma biblioteca para integrar com Xamarin. Para resolver o problema criei uma webview que renderiza uma página web formatada para celular.